# Give access to a specific user to a specific folder within a group? [Terminal]

Tags: permissions, users

I have created a file, admin, that I want to assign to a group, admingroup, and later on give a specific user, adminuser, exclusive access to that file but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very easy in POSIX based systems.

First

`chown adminuser:admingroup admin`

That will make the owner of the file specificly adminuser and the entire group admingroup.

Then you will likely want to:

`chmod a-rwx admin`
`chomd ug+rwx admin`

That will remove all permissions from admin and then give user and group access to read write and execute the admin file.

[This is a very decent tutorial](http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/linux-file-permissions) on file permissions, though there are better ones. This should get you started though.

Comment: You could also run `chmod o-rwx` to just remove others abaility to read/write/execute, or use about a hundred other methods. Use `ls -lah` to view permissions on files.